# ScrollReveal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollreveal.js

I'm doing everything the internet says, the exact same coding, step by step. Doesn't seem to work for me.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.sr = new ScrollReveal();
    sr.reveal('bluprintdesign');
</script>
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<div class="center" style="top: 3%;">
        <img data-sr id="bluprintdesign" src="img/bluprint-design.png" alt="bluprint logo" style="width: 15%;"> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to scrollreveal github page there is no keyword **new** in front of ScrollReveal();

```
window.sr = ScrollReveal();
sr.reveal('bluprintdesign');
```

if this doesn't solve the issue, please check the dev console and see if any errors pop up.

Comment: Did what you said, and no errors popped up. Still not working :-/

Comment: Alright can you show us where you input the <script> tags inside the .html ?

Comment: <script> was inserted in the <body> tag at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

```
sr.reveal('bluprintdesign');
```

To this:

```
sr.reveal('#bluprintdesign');
```